# lista.clear() vs lista = new ArrayList<T>()

Tags: java, lista

Para remover todos os itens de uma lista, posso fazer de duas formas: `lista.clear()` e `lista = new ArrayList<T>()`.

Quais são as diferenças entre elas?

Em quais situações devo utilizar cada uma?

Comment: @bigown procurei antes e não encontrei. Obrigado pelas respostas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando vc utiliza `list.clear()` você realmente limpa a lista e se aproveita do mesmo espaço em memoria onde ela já está alocada.

Quando vc utiliza `list = new ArrayList<>()` vc cria uma nova instância em memória (outro espaço para armazenar a lista) e atribui este novo endereço para a lista que vc faz a referência, desta forma fica em responsabilidade do garbage collector remover a instância que não será mais utilizada em memória. Caso você deseje criar uma nova lista, mas não deseja ter o efeito colateral de limpar a lista atual, crie uma nova variável. Isso pode ser útil quando a variável `list` é compartilhada e não se deseja mexer em seu conteúdo.

Se `list` não é usado em outro local, o ideal para melhor otimização e desempenho é utilizar o `list.clear()`.